# How to Show and Download a file in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am working to upload a file and then displaying their list using web API. The file name should be a link so that on click of it the file should be download or user can see it. Here is my code.

**Controller**

```
  public ActionResult CreateFiles(long? clientId, long? freelancerId)
        {
            string apiEventCommon = string.Format("api/client/{0}/Event/Common", UserSession.ClientId);
            EventCommon eventCommon = HttpHandler.Get<EventCommon>(apiEventCommon, UserSession.AccessToken);
            FileInfoModel createFiles = new FileInfoModel();
            createFiles.AllFiles = eventCommon.FileTypes;
            createFiles.ClientId = Convert.ToInt64(UserSession.ClientId);
            createFiles.FreelancerId = 9;//hardcoded 
            clientId = createFiles.ClientId;//temp
            freelancerId = 9;//temp
            if (clientId != null && freelancerId != null)
            {
                string api = string.Format("api/client/{0}/freelancer/{1}/files", clientId, freelancerId);
                var fileDetail = HttpHandler.Get<List<FilesDetails>>(api, UserSession.AccessToken);
                createFiles.ExistingFiles = fileDetail;
            }
            return View(createFiles);
        }
```

**View**

```
  @foreach (var file in Model.ExistingFiles)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @{
                                    var length = @file.FileName.Length - 1;
                                }
                                @(@file.FileName.Length > 10 ? @file.FileName.Substring(0, 10) + "..." : @file.FileName)
                            </td>
                            <td>@file.FileSize</td>
                            <td>@file.UploadDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ClientId)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FreelancerId)

                                <a class="posDelete" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <span id="fileSpan" class="noti glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" style="color:#D3B06E" onclick="DeleteFile('@file.Id','@file.FreelancerId','@file.Filecategory','@file.FileName');"></span>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                                    }
```

I am saving files to my project directory and I am saving their path in database. So how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a html link to the file, the same way you can have links to other elements in your page.

```
<a href='path_to_the_file_or_page'>link_description</a>
```

The file should be accesible using the browser, so the link is not broken.